# Running Stack as super user

Tags: linux, haskell, sudo, haskell-stack

I am trying to run the [honk package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/honk). Since this package has not been ported to Stackage, I started a new Stack project, copied the source files, and setup the .cabal file. It builds ok.

Now when I am trying to run a simple 1 liner program (`main = playOne $ Note 1 440`) I get a "permission denied" message on execution: `beepOpen: permission denied (Permission denied)`

This is normal and documented [here](https://lambda.xyz/honk/learn/), as "*under Linux, for security reasons, only the root user can control the PC speaker.*" (*)

I tried to "sudo" stack commands (as in `sudo stack ghci` or `sudo stack exec myprogram-exe`) but I only get a `sudo: stack: command not found` error message back. I am mostly interested in running this program under ghci.

**My question** : how to run `stack ghci` as root and get this running? Also, if there is a way to `stack exec` as root, I am interested to know too.

(*) I am on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

Comment: You could try running `stack exec bash` and then `sudo ghci`.

Comment: @sjakobi. Sorry I'm not aware of `stack exec bash` and `sudo ghci` doesn't seem to work either. Do you mind explaining?